# Can someone tell me what this symbol is. Strongly believed to originated from Hong Kong a long time ago

Tags: character-identification

[image]Inherited this ring and looking to learn more about it.

Comment: About how long ago ? Would you please explain what made you believe it's a Chinese stuff, not a British one ?

Comment: It belonged to my dad (Chinese and born and raised in Hong Kong) he came to uk just over 50 years ago and had the ring then , have a photo of him in Hong Kong wearing it before he moved.

Comment: @Miranda I totally believe your father got this ring in hong kong, however I don't believe it has any chinese symbolism.  From a chinese view it appears to be simply abstract art.  If it does have symbolism I believe it is probably not chinese in nature :)

Comment: If you don't mind, could you tell us what line of work your dad did while in Hong Kong, so that we could pin down some basic parameters? However, it looks like an Astrological Symbol. What month was your dad born?

Comment: My dad was born 9th February and whilst in Hong Kong he was a policeman (water patrol) Kowloon way

Comment: I have never seen such a symbol in Hong Kong. Maybe a (former) memeber of the police force would know.